# C++ binary '+'; no global operator found which takes type 'Pair'

Tags: c++

In Main.cpp why does `p3 = p3 + 2;` work but `p3 = 2 + p3;` gives me the error stated in the title?

Pair.h

```
#pragma once
class Pair
{
private:
    int num1, num2;
public:
    Pair();
    Pair(int num1, int num2);
    int get1();
    int get2();
    Pair operator+(const Pair& other);
    Pair operator+(int otherNum);
};
```

Pair.cpp

```
#include "Pair.h"
Pair::Pair() : num1(0), num2(0)
{
}
Pair::Pair(int num1, int num2) : num1(num1), num2(num2)
{
}
int Pair::get1()
{
    return num1;
}
int Pair::get2()
{
    return num2;
}
// Return a new pair that adds the corresponding numbers
Pair Pair::operator+(const Pair& other)
{
    Pair newPair(this->num1, this->num2);
    newPair.num1 += other.num1;
    newPair.num2 += other.num2;
    return newPair;
}
// Return a new pair that adds otherNum to num1 and num2
Pair Pair::operator+(int otherNum)
{
    Pair newPair(this->num1, this->num2);
    newPair.num1 += otherNum;
    newPair.num2 += otherNum;
    return newPair;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Pair.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Pair p1(5, 10);
    Pair p2(1, 2);
    // Outputs 5 and 10
    cout << p1.get1() << " " << p1.get2() << endl;
    // Outputs 1 and 2
    cout << p2.get1() << " " << p2.get2() << endl;
    Pair p3 = p2 + p1;
    // Outputs 6 and 12
    cout << p3.get1() << " " << p3.get2() << endl;

    p3 = p3 + 2;

    // doesn't work
    //p3 = 2 + p3;

    // Outputs 8 and 14
    cout << p3.get1() << " " << p3.get2() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Because addition is not commutative in C++. You need to define a `Pair operator+(int, const Pair&)`. It should be a `friend` function of the `Pair` class. See the second column of the first table on this page https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators. In C++, operators on non built-in types are just functions, and like other functions they have a name and a parameter order.

Comment: Something is still wrong. Adding ```Pair operator+(const int&, const Pair&);``` under the Pair class does not work.

Comment: Does it have the `friend` function specifier? Because if not, and it's inside the class, there's an implicit first parameter `this` passed into the function. Please let us know in which way it does not work (specific code and error message, sometimes it makes sense to make a new question).

Comment: Look at this link (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) about half way down the page under **Binary arithmetic operators**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an `operator+` for the operation you want to make. You already have an `operator+` that takes a `Pair` and an `int` (in that order). This one can be a member function of `Pair`, since each non-static member function of a class has an implicit `this` as a first parameter.

Your function prototype should look like

```
Pair operator+(int num, const Pair& otherPair)
```

Since you want a function that doesn't take a `Pair` as the first parameter, you cannot make this a member function of `Pair`. That implicit `this` in the member function would prevent that.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

---

#### Suggested: Have the `+(int, Pair)` function call the `+(Pair, int)` function

You need to:
  1. Declare the function in your `Pair.h` file
  2. Define the function in your `Pair.cpp` file

Since this is not a member function, you can either declare it outside of the `Pair` class, or make it a `friend` function within the `Pair` class (which the compiler treats as being outside of the class, but gives direct access to private members of the class).

```
// Pair.h
#pragma once
class Pair
{
    // keep this the same as in your question, OP
};

Pair operator+(int num, const Pair& other); // <--- add this
```

```
// Pair.cpp

// keep this the same as in your question, OP

// add this
Pair operator+(int num, const Pair& other) // <-- NOT Pair::operator+
{
    return other + num; // <-- simply calls Pair::operator+(int)
}
```

This method also makes maintenance easier. You don't have to worry about updating two identical functions. You just update the one in the class namespace.

---

#### Not suggested (but possible): Have the `+(int, Pair)` function provide its own implementation, using `friend` specifier

Since the above operation `int + Pair` is as easy as calling the commutative `Pair + int`, there's no need to make it `friend` (despite me harping on it in the comments). But if there was ever a reason your `int + Pair` operation was not commutative with `Pair + int`, you would need to provide its own implementation, which likely would require accessing `private` member variables. In that case you would need to make this a `friend` function.

This is provided for completion; I suggest using the above method.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend

```
// Pair.h
#pragma once
class Pair
{
    // keep this the same as in your question, OP

    friend Pair operator+(int num, const Pair& other); // <--- add this
};
```

```
// Pair.cpp

// keep this the same as in your question, OP

// add this
Pair operator+(int num, const Pair& other) // <-- still NOT Pair::operator+
{
    // example implementation to differ from +(Pair, int)
    Pair newPair(other.num1, other.num2);
    newPair.num2 += num; // only increment num2
    return newPair;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined operator+ as a member function of Pair.

So when you write `p + 2` the compiler knows you want to apply +2 on object p.

Instead, if you want to allow int + Pair, you need to define an operator outside your class:

```
Pair operator+(const int&, const Pair&);
```

Similarly,

```
Pair operator+(const Pair&, const int&);
```

will allow Pair + int.

Comment: Generally in the same file as `Pair`, just outside of the `class Pair` scope. That way any other file that `#include "Pair.h"` has access to the required operators. You could also put it INSIDE of the `class Pair` scope, but put the keyword `friend` in front of it. That would make it not part of the `Pair` namespace, but still give it access to `Pair`'s private variables.

Comment: `Pair operator+(const int&, const Pair&);` still gives me a error when I add it into Pair.h so something still isnt correct. 
```Error (active) E0344 too many parameters for this operator function```

Comment: @sewyut It's not a member function of the class. Put the declaration outside.

Comment: I put it at the end of Pair.h under the Pair class. It doesn't allow me to do that. Unresolved externals error. Any other ideas?